# Как установить контейнер в header справа?

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять почему личный кабинет не уходит вправо!?
http://zonnon.com.ua#top-links

как не крути не встает справа! пробовал уже и бутстраповскими классами и что угодно, просто что-то не дает срабботать float:right!
помогите разобратся!( 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/186999)

Comment: Так а не легче посмотреть в инспекторе человеку который разбирается и помочь? нежели я сбда выложу 100 строк html кода , при том что в итоге может оказатся что свойство не так где-то задано или в опенкарте вообще иначе надо это делать...

Comment: Конечно не легче: во-первых, нужно идти на какой-то левый сайт, во-вторых, по вопросу непонятно что именно не встает справа, в-третьих, сюда не надо выкладывать 100 строк html, сюда надо добавить [mcve], который будет демонстрировать ошибку, а не копировать полностью весь сайт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай свой контейнер для хедера как `block`, а не `flex`:

[image: code]

**RESULT:**
[image: screen]

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!)